# How to add a filter & sort button in cell?

Tags: excel, excel-2013, dropdown

How can I insert the filter and sort button in the cell as in the picture?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

or better, click on a cell that is filled in, and then  "Home">>"Format as Table". It gives you a lot of options regarding filtering, sorting and formula copy plus some interesting design.

[Format as Table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2deA.jpg)

Comment: Mind = Blown! I was working on a sub to add `filter` to the ws, that went fine, then I wanted to also add a one click button for sort, but seems thats not possible, it's just build as filter. But, I love the "table" option way more, much more new things to explore now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to go along w/ George's answer of using a Table.

I immediatley ran into trouble adding tables when filters work fine. You can't convert a "query" range to a table, but you can add a filter. See --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/40492129/5079799 & Disclaimer This is my blog where I will post updated code https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/display/FREES/Filter+Worksheet+-+Table+-+Query+-+Excel+VBA

```
Public Sub DatatoTable(ws As Worksheet)
   
    Dim TblStyle As String
    TblStyle = "TableStyleMedium20"
    
    Dim TblName As String
    TblName = ws.Name
     
    Dim TblRng As Range
    Set TblRng = GetUsedRange(ws)
    
    ws.Activate
    TblRng.Select
    Set lo = TblRng.ListObject
    If Not lo Is Nothing Then
         Debug.Print "Table Found"
    Else
     ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, TblRng, , xlYes).Name = TblName
     Range(TblName & "[#All]").Select
     ws.ListObjects(TblName).TableStyle = TblStyle
    End If
End Sub
Public Function GetUsedRange(ws As Worksheet) As Range
 Dim lRow As Integer, lCol As Integer, fCol As Integer, fRow As Integer
 fCol = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlLeft).Column
 lCol = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
 fRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlDown).Row
 lRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
 Set GetUsedRange = ws.Range(Cells(fRow, fCol), Cells(lRow, lCol))
End Function
Sub Test()
 
 Call DatatoTable(ActiveSheet)
 
End Sub
```