# Determining if a cell is linked to a QueryTable via VBA in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm linking an Excel worksheet to a data source using QueryTables which works well. I'd like to introduce logic to check a given cell and determine if that cell is the top left corner of an existing QueryTable. This seemed trivial in concept, but has proven elusive in practice. If I try to check any properties of the cell that relate to QueryTable I get an error. i.e. `rng.querytable` throws error 1004 if `rng` does not link to a QueryTable. So I messed around with testing if `rng.ListObject is nothing` based on some discussions I found online. It turns out that `rng.ListObject` is something if the cell is a table even if that table is not a QueryTable. So no dice there.

So how do I test if a target cell contains a QueryTable?

Here's a stub of my function I got from [Mr. Excel](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/152383-querytable-query.html):

```
Public Function IsRangeInQueryTable(rngCheck As Range) As Boolean
    Dim QT As QueryTable

    For Each QT In rngCheck.Parent.QueryTables

        If Not Intersect(rngCheck, QT.ResultRange) Is Nothing Then
            IsRangeInQueryTable = True
            Exit Function
        End If

    Next QT

    'If it got to here then the specified range does not lie
    'in the result range of any query
    IsRangeInQueryTable = False

End Function
```

The function above works in many cases, but if I have QueryTables that have become detached from their destination (which seems to happen in practice) the code throws error 1004 because the QueryTable has no destination. Here's what the watch shows when the QueryTable becomes decoupled from a destination:

[image]

FWIW, I also tried approaching this the reverse way and iterating through every QueryTable in a worksheet. It turns out if there's a QueryTable which has had its destination deleted, asking that QueryTable for its `QueryTable.Destination` throws an app error. So I could not figure out a reliable way to do that approach either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wordier than it needs to be, but because the "OnError" statement redirects all errors, I want to eliminate the possibility of accidentally handling the wrong error, for example if `rng` was `Nothing`.

```
Public Function cell_has_query(rng As Range) As Boolean

    If rng Is Nothing Then
       cell_has_query = False
       Exit Function
    End If

    If rng.ListObject Is Nothing Then
        cell_has_query = False
        Exit Function
    End If

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    If Not rng.ListObject.QueryTable Is Nothing Then
        cell_has_query = True
    End If
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then 'Application-Defined or Object-Defined Error
        cell_has_query = False
    Else
        On Error GoTo 0
        Resume
    End If
End Function
```

@JDLong VBA error handling is odd. The default setting for errors is `On Error GoTo 0`, which means that (depending upon your VBA IDE settings; Tools-->Options-->General) will pop up a message box for unhandled errors. If you want to explicitly catch and handle errors, you create a label (e.g. "ErrHandler") and then make sure that section of code is unreachable normally by ending the function with `Exit Function`. In the block of code after the label, you can inspect the `Err` object properties and choose to `Resume` to retry the line of code that caused the error, `Resume Next` to run the line *following* the one that errored, or simply handle the error and let the function exit normally. You can also reraise the error by setting the mode back to `On Error GoTo 0` and then `Resume`ing the line.

Comment: I went down that route earlier and found that rng.ListObject is something if the rng is a table, even if it does not have a querytable. So that situation ends up passing the first check (listobject is something) then throwing error on the second check.

Comment: @JDLong I see what you mean - I just tried with an Excel table. This is not actually an issue because you can use VBA error handling to catch it.  If that line of code throws a 1004 error, it can be concluded that it is *not* a QueryTable. One sec and I'll rewrite

Comment: I was struggling how to do that without a try/catch (VBA is clearly not the language I'm most used to thinking in)

Comment: @JDLong I started in C++, used Java for a couple years, then got stuck with VBA for the past several years - I feel your pain :P

Comment: @JDLong I added a quick crash course on VBA error handling there for you - if you need clarification leave a comment!

Comment: that's amazingly helpful. Thank you. Using the error block to effectively handle the "Catch" of a try/catch block seems obvious in retrospect, but I was not able to get my mind there yesterday. Much appreciated.

Comment: @JDLong In case you're interested, [here is some documentation on how error handling in VBA works](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3211/error-handling#t=201611081540563470364).

Comment: oddly I had to remove the .listobject references above. My querytables do not appear to be in a listobject. That totally blows my mental model of how this all works.

Answer (score 2):

for some reason that is not clear to me, my querytables are not in listobjects. I thought all querytables are in listobjects, but I've run enough tests to demonstrate to myself that mine are not. So I slightly edited @blackhawk's function to this:

```
Public Function cell_has_query(rng As Range) As Boolean

    If rng Is Nothing Then
       cell_has_query = False
       Exit Function
    End If

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    If Not rng.QueryTable Is Nothing Then
        cell_has_query = True
    End If
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then 'Application-Defined or Object-Defined Error - this throws if there is a querytable with no destination
        cell_has_query = False
    Else
        On Error GoTo 0
        Resume
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: The Excel object model has a pretty decent underlying hierarchy (the "has" parent/child relationships), but in addition to that things are linked to each other all over the place which complicates things... In this case, the parent Worksheet has Range and QueryTable children, but any relationship between those two directly is going to be less straightforward

Comment: I'll print this to explain to my daughter why daddy drinks.

Comment: @JDLong, can't explain why as I'm not willing to debug, but your answer had the correct Boolean result for function vs https://stackoverflow.com/a/40476268/5079799